# Sending email no longer working on Ubuntu 14.04.1 after deploying with Meteor Up

Tags: meteor, smtp, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean, meteor-up

Recently I added email sending capability to my Meteor app, using both the email package, and the account registration APIs to send emails. The other day, after having tested this thoroughly on my dev machine, I deployed it to our production server using Meteor Up. Once deployed, I did a quick check that the email APIs were working properly, and let it be. A day or two later, I made some minor changes, wrapping these email APIs in a Meteor.defer method to speed up the UI. I tested the changes locally (all fine), and re-deployed. I also ran apt-get update on my server after seeing a notification there were some new security updates available. After doing this, the email system no longer works. I tried reverting back to my previous configuration, and it still isn't working. I'm getting a timeout error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'forgotPassword' Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on what might be causing this timeout (a blocked port?...how can I diagnose this?). Given my SMTP port is working on my development machine, it doesn't seem to be an issue with my code, but rather either with the MUP deployment, or Ubuntu configuration. I'm not super familiar with configuring Ubuntu servers. Any suggestions on how to go about de-bugging would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to connect to the mail server via telnet?

Comment: No I didn't. Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: telnet <servername> <port>

Comment: It appears to hang when trying this...

Comment: Apparently it was a block put on the server by my hosting provider to prevent spam...it's in the process of being fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

We got a similar problem, and it was solved by opening the needed port in EC2. thanks to https://kylegoslin.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/116/